# How can I send an HTML file in JavaMail?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I am using the Google App Engine and JavaMail.  I need to send some email sized html mail messages to users after specific events.  How can I send them with JavaMail? (They are 60 - 100 lines of HTML so trying to add it a line at a time is fairly unreasonable. Any way to add it all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
String message ="<b>This is my message!</b>"

Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setContent(message, "text/html");
```

All's you really need to do then is read your file into a String.

For example see [how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) 
or [java-how-to-read-complete-text-file](http://abhinandanmk.blogspot.jp/2012/05/java-how-to-read-complete-text-file.html)

Comment: That was my first thought but I really hoped there was a more elegant way than creating a 15000 character String :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a templating framework to help generate your email content. These are simple to implement and several of them work well in the App Engine environment.

I have used the following:

- [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/)
- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

And found that both do the job well. These templating engines are fairly powerful and do include things like conditional logic, processing records of similar data, etc.

At a high level, it would be something like this:
1) Define your email templates (in HTML) and put them into some `WEB-INF/email-templates` folder. These template formats will depend on the templating engine that you use. Most of them will have substitutable parameters e.g. Hello ${name}, etc.

2) At runtime, determine the email that you want to send. All you will need to tell the templating engine will be which template file and a map of parameters that will be replaced by the engine itself. The output will be a HTML formatted string that you could then use.

Comment: Wow Romin u r a life saver !. using Freemarker currently .

Answer (score 0):

If you want something a little more modern you could try [Handlebars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java).

Alternatively, I've built a lightweight webframework designed for use on AppEngine called [thundr](http://3wks.github.io/thundr/) . Using this you can render email bodies using any templating language it supports, including jsps. This lets you have a unified templating language for both web presentation and emails. Makes life a bit easier over using one language for web and one for emails.